# Remap Swedish MacBook air keyboard linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, macbook, keyboard-layout, manjaro

I have a MacBook air from 2014 with a Swedish keyboard layout and manjaro Linux installed (based on arch). Upon installation I chose the Swedish keyboard layout but the right alt + 7 doesn't output a starting curly brace as expected. Does anyone know how to remap this? Right alt + 0 does output a ending curly brace, so the issue is only present on 1 key.